# add custom banner on specific product view page

Tags: layout, xml, product-view-page

I tried to add a banner for a specific product but when I looked for the options,
I can add in the content of the product, but I need the banner on the top of the **specific product view page**.

Is there's any way to add the banner or the html content on the **top** of the **specific product view page?**

Comment: i think first you create enable or disable custom attrbiute  in product section admin side.And second you create the custom module and apply the condition if `custom_attribute` enable show banner and disable else out of if condition